# Creating an Always-Updating Database

Tags: sql

I have a table with pre-defined columns that require a user input for each column--so this will this be a table that will be constantly updating? Would this be best solved with MDS? What are my other options? Currently we track the table in an Excel spreadsheet but it's becoming quite cumbersome and I'd like to migrate this into a SQL database and I'd like to continue updating it in the database via user inputs.